# Wordpress - Rev Slider not replacing shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, revolution-slider

So, Basically I have a Revolutionary Slider plugin installed and created one slider. I added the shortcode :

```
[rev_slider alias="home-original"]
```

on the homepage. But the slider is just not replacing with the shortcode. The shortcode is displaying as it is on the homepage. I also tried the do_shortcode() function in the header.php but the same occurs.

When I tried this

```
shortcode_exists('rev_slider')
```

It prints false.
I also tried this

```
 $active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );
```

And it shows the rev slider is active.
What more should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to manually add shortcode in PHP:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[rev_slider alias="slideshow"]' ); ?>
```

Maybe you forgot to use **echo**